# "downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer" in Firefox when font hosted on the web

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, font-face

I am trying to use a custom font (format woff2). The font works well in Chrome (whether on local files or when the html and font files are hosted on the web), but it fails to load on Firefox when the html page and font are hosted on the web with the following error:

```
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "My Sans Regular" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0) source: https://host/resources/my_sans_reg_web.woff2
```

Here is how the font is specified in the page:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My Sans Regular';
    src: url('resources/my_sans_reg_web.woff2') format('woff2');
}
body, span, button, input, textarea, form, mark, table, th, td, p, h4, h5, a {
    font-family: 'My Sans Regular';
}
```

The size of the font file is 41kb, so it cannot be a memory issue (as suggested here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/913498 ).
I researched the issue on the web and on this site, but I could not find a solution or an issue that matched exactly mine.
I am using Firefox version 91.13.0esr.

Comment: How have you created the web font? I suggest using a tool like https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator to make sure it's compatible with the maximum number of browsers.

Comment: Hi @Christian, 
It was created by the organization I work for. So, I am not sure how it was created. But note that the same font file works fine when it is loaded from a local file (and if it were corrupted when it was hosted, why would it work for Chrome?).

Comment: Could be because Chrome has either a laziest validation check, or FF has more strict validation rules about what constitutes an acceptable font format.
What happens when you use FontSquirrel (see link in previous comment) or an equivalent 'Web Font Generator' tool?

Comment: Interesting... https://www.fontsquirrel.com/ Says: "The font 'my_sans_reg_web.woff2' is corrupt and cannot be converted." But the weird thing is that the web page is expecting these extensions: otf, ttf, and txt. Mine is a woff.
Thanks for the tip. I will do some more digging...

Comment: I ended up using a different approach and got rid of the woff2 file.